# Changing light switch, help with wiring needed

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I changed my old lightbulbs to dimmable LEDs, now I need to change the switch accordingly.

Before: (stacked switches from top to bottom) small light switch 1, small light switch 2, small switch for fan.

After, what I need: (large switches side by side) dimmable switch 1, dimmable switch 2, switch for fan.

What I managed to do so far: re-wired the small light switch 1 to dimmable switch 1, it works perfectly. This is what is shown in picture #1: left side shows the stacked switches, the top one is re-wired to the dimmable switch on the right.

I need help with re-wiring the second dimmable switch, plus the fan switch (not on the picture).

1. I'm not sure about the exact function of the two power cords (each white and black cable)
   EDIT: white is grounded, black is not grounded.
2. Can someone explain the meaning of 0, 1 and 3 on the back side of the switches?
   Is this some sort of universal standard or specific to Japanese?

Any advice or hint is appreciated!

EDIT: the red wire with the dimmable switch is it's out of the box state.

[image: what I've done so far]

Comment: Did this dimmer come with documentation?

Comment: Where on this planet are you?

Comment: Yes, but it's in Japanese, here's a quick link to it (middle of page where it says WTC57521W): http://www2.panasonic.biz/es/densetsu/haisen/switch_concent/switch/switch08.html

Comment: @Harper or here's a picture with the documentation: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdMmP.jpg

Comment: We still need to know where on the planet you are to answer this...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sorry to miss that, that would be Japan

Comment: Did you find an answer? Looks like you may be in Japan. I’m having an issue trying to change a regular switch over to a dimmer switch. The problem I’m having is the regular switch has a ground but the new dimmer switch doesn’t have a space for the ground. I was also curious about the 0,1,3 numbers but I may just call an electrician to install rather than accidentally catch my home on fire.

Comment: @Mike Sorry to be late, but I ended up calling an electrician who solved my problem